# Debug Javascript file in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to debug javascript file in visual studio but everytime when i insert breakpoint and run the code, the breakpoint says

> 'The breakpoint will not currently be hit. The specified module has
>   not been loaded'

and i cannot debug the javascript file. i know it is possible to debug js file in Visual studio since i did that before i formatted my same computer. But after i installed new instance of Visual Studio, i am unable to debug it.
P.S: The Silverlight checkbox is unchecked and Asp.net and Native Code checkboxes is checked under Debuggers. It's a web project and i have Resharper 6 installed.

Please help?? sick and tired of hitting F12 in IE to debug js file.

Comment: Have you configured ie to support external debuggers.

Comment: i use chrome primarily, so i dont want to do it in ie.

Comment: i don't think js debugging feature inside vs is available for any browser other than ie.

Comment: darn..u are right Pratik. I just changed my default browser to IE and voila debugger just works like charm. it's lame that i only works for IE. Thanks much :))

Answer (score 0):

I've never gotten it to work in VS... but Chrome's script debugger is quite good.

Comment: just make IE as default browser and it just works fine..which is lame.

Answer (score -1):

you can debug via Browser,
if you a Mozilla user download Firebug at http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: i knw how to do it in browser, but as i said i want it in VS